# Use a named range as an email list in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new here and just learning to code. I'm working on an Excel form and I need to use a named a range on a separate work sheet as an email list. Is there a way to add this to the .To= field?

```
Private Sub Email_Click()
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xMailBody As String
On Error Resume Next
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
xMailBody = Range("G2") & " Shift Turnover Report is attached"
              On Error Resume Next
With xOutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Range("G2") & " Shift Turnover Report"
    .Body = xMailBody
    .Attachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Send
End With
If Err Then
  MsgBox "Hmmm. Something went wrong." & vbLf & "Please try again.", vbExclamation
Else
  MsgBox "Your message has been sent.", vbInformation
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `.To = Range("EmailNamedRange").Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Dim x, Emails()
Dim strEmails As String

x = Range("EmailNamedRange").Value
Emails() = Application.Index(x, 0, 1)

strEmails = Join(Application.Transpose(Emails), ";")

With xOutMail
    .To = strEmails
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Range("G2") & " Shift Turnover Report"
    .Body = xMailBody
    .Attachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: @N.Benedict You're welcome! Glad it worked as desired. Please take a minute to accept the answer and mark your question as Solved.